# Exclude a folder from SVN checkout on Aptana

Tags: svn, aptana

I have a site developed with cakePHP. I have it under source control with svn. I develop it with the Aptana Studio, both in Linux and in windows.

there are some directories like app/tmp which as the name says holds temporary data. Is it possible to omit the folder for being checked by aptana studio where to be commited?
I right-clicked on the folder and applied a svn propert svn-ignore: *

But still every time I want to commit those files/folders appear in my list of changed files.

Comment: This question is about Aptana and SVN Reposity, not CakePHP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if the folder is already in svn, you should remove it from source control (using 'svn delete').

Then you should set the svn:ignore (note the colon instead of the dash) property on the *parent* folder to include the folder name that you want to ignore.

so for app\tmp, set svn:ignore on 'app' to 'tmp'

Comment: But svn delete deletes the folder from my proect also. I want it to stay there

Comment: @gong, svn does not physically delete the folder from your drive, does it? If it is removed from your project, that may be a 'feature' of your Aptana/svn plugin. What happens if you re-add the folder (after having performed the above steps)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think that if you set an svn-ignore property on a folder you will have to commit that folder before it will start working.

Comment: You have to set the svn:ignore property before the folder is even committed to SVN.  It's useless if the file/folder to be ignored is already under source control.

Comment: I meant the containing folder. (That is the folder you set the property on)

Answer (score 0):

jeroenh add :

if the folder is already in svn :
Switch to SVN Repositories and delete what you want.
Switch to Project Explorer and Team > Update to Version.
And then do what jeroenh said